# Hook the method whose parameters contain unknown object

Tags: c++, hook, detours

I hooked a C++ member method via detours.

The method's declaration is retrieved from Symbol file (*.pdb) in IDA

```
LPVOID __thiscall Foo(class UnknownClass, unsigned int, int)
```

The following is my method replacing the real one

```
// the first parameter of the method is an unknown class to me
// I don't know its implementation, don't know its size
// so I just declare a dummy class with a enough size
class UnknownClass { public: CHAR dummy[1024]; };

typedef LPVOID (__thiscall MyDummyClass::*PFN_Foo)( UnknownClass, unsigned int, int );

class MyDummyClass
{
public:
    // The address of the real method
    PFN_Foo m_pfnFoo;

    // My method to replace the real one
    LPVOID MyFoo( UnknownClass p1, unsigned int p2, int p3)
    {
        MyDummyClass * pThis = (MyDummyClass*)this;

        // call the real one.
        // and here the error happens 
        return (pThis->*m_pfnFoo)( p1, p2, p3 );
    }
};
```

The hook works and `MyFoo` is called instead of the real method. but I get an error when calling the real method:

> `Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>    across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>    function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>    declared with a different calling convention.`

Do you have any suggestion to me? How to handle this kind of hook when one of the parameter is passed as object, but its implementation is unknown to me.

Comment: You need to get the exact sizes of the object right, as well as potentially calling any destructors. Without debug symbols or headers, that's going to be a bit challenging. You may need to recreate more of the class than just a buffer. However, *do not use Detours*. It's touchy and unstable, known to crash when running on systems it doesn't like, and makes this sort of thing a lot harder than it needs to be. EasyHook or a similar library will provide a much better experience.

Comment: changed to EasyHook, still the same :(

Comment: Are you sure p1 is passed by value? if it is, your choice of 1024 bytes causes quite a lot of stuff to be pushed on the stack.

Comment: I don't know the exact size of the object, and I guess it will trigger the "copy constructor" for the object when I pass the object. don't know how to resolve it

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985969/copyitems-function-hook-crashes